# Thread over a nested list top to bottom until non-list elements are found

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list:

```
list = {1, 2, {3, 4}, f[a], {2, h[b]}}
```

I would like to apply a function `g` to all elements of the nested list (starting from top to bottom) that are not lists themselves. That is, I would like to obtain:

```
{g[1], g[2], {g[3], g[4]},  g[f[a]], {g[2], g[h[b]]}}
```

(Using `Map[g, list, {-1}]` does not work, as it maps `g` inside `f` and `h`)

The alternative I have ended up using is the following function:

```
mapAtLeavesOfList[g_, x_List] := Map[mapAtLeavesOfList[g, #] &, x]
mapAtLeavesOfList[g_, x_] := g[x]

mapAtLeavesOfList[g, list]
=> {g[1], g[2], {g[3], g[4]}, g[f[a]], {g[2], g[h[b]]}}
```

Any better suggestions?

Comment: This feels like a duplicate to me.  Does anyone know what I may be remembering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what the title claims, your example shows that do not want to map at the "maximum depth" of the list, but rather, merely onto the elements of a `List` that are not lists themselves. I think you're over complicating things with your definition of `mapAtLeavesOfList`.

The solution is as simple as:

```
Clear@g
g[a_List] := g /@ a

g@list
(* {g[1], g[2], {g[3], g[4]}, g[f[a]], {g[2], g[h[b]]}} *)
```

If you want to use `g` as a blackbox function, the following should work:

```
Block[{mapg},
    mapg[a_List] := mapg /@ a;
    mapg@list /. mapg -> g
]
```

or even:

```
Block[{g},
    g[a_List] := g /@ a;
    g@list
]
```

The above solution temporarily modifies `g` to make it listable using `Block` and once outside the `Block`, the original definition of `g` kicks in.

You can also set the `Listable` attribute for `g` as in Leonid's answer.

Comment: In the spirit of your last suggestion, one could also do something like `Block[{g}, g[list] //. x_g :> Thread[x]]`

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the title to better reflect the question.

Comment: @ecoxlinux But the title still misses the point - what you ask is not mapping on leaves, you rather ask to thread over the lists top to bottom until non-lists are encountered.

Comment: Thanks to both of you (leonid and hypnotoad). Hypnotoad, I was indeed overcomplicating the issue.

Answer (score 5):

A few other alternatives: either you can make `g` itself a `Listable` function by executing `SetAttributes[g,Listable]` (assuming that `g` is a symbol), or you can do something like this:

```
Function[Null, g[#], Listable][list]
```

where I don't make any assumptions on `g` (which may be a symbol but may be something else).

Note that there are subtle differences between setting `g` Listable and defining `g[a_List] := g /@ a`. The latter method is less general in two respects. First, you may not be able to add a new definition, for whatever reason. Second, this won't work if `g` carries `Hold` - attributes (`HoldAll` or `HoldFirst`) - because they will prevent the pattern `g[a_List]` from matching, if you pass a variable such as `list`. The methods based on `Listable` attribute are free from this particular limitation.

Comment: @Rojo Yes, you are right. Will edit.