# Elementwise join

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

I have two tensors of arbitrary but equal rank n (and equal dimensions): `A` and `B`, and I want to get a third tensor of rank n + 1, `C`.

I want to do a element by element `Join`, so the element in `A` and the corresponding element in `B` are contracted into a list in `C`.

For example, with n = 2:

```
A = {{a[0,0],a[1,0]},{a[0,1],a[1,1]}};
B = {{b[0,0],b[1,0]},{b[0,1],b[1,1]}};
```

then:

```
C = {{ {a[0,0],b[0,0]} , {a[1,0],b[1,0]} },{ {a[0,1],b[0,1]} , {a[1,1],b[1,1]} }}
```

I think it might be doable with some combination of `Inner` and `List`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note: `C` is a built-in symbol in ``System` `` and it's not wise to assign/modify it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I was using `A`, `B` and `C` as example variables.

Comment: This is very strongly related, although the way the two questions are worded, they're entirely different http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17291/5

Comment: Related: [(6102)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6102/121), [(9012)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9012/121)

Answer (score 10):

Here are a couple of possibilities.

```
MapThread[Riffle[{#1}, {#2}] &, {aA, bB}, 2]

(* Out[64]= {{{a[0, 0], b[0, 0]}, {a[1, 0], b[1, 0]}}, {{a[0, 1], 
   b[0, 1]}, {a[1, 1], b[1, 1]}}} *)

Transpose[ArrayFlatten[{aA, bB}], {3, 1, 2}]

(* Out[72]= {{{a[0, 0], b[0, 0]}, {a[1, 0], b[1, 0]}}, {{a[0, 1], 
   b[0, 1]}, {a[1, 1], b[1, 1]}}} *)
```

Another that I like less:

```
Map[Thread, Thread[{aA, bB}]]
```

--- edit ---

Actually that second one should just be

```
Transpose[{aA, bB}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

The ArrayFlatten was not needed in this case (it can be useful somethimes though). And in case it was not clear, the lists are:

```
aA = {{a[0, 0], a[1, 0]}, {a[0, 1], a[1, 1]}};
bB = {{b[0, 0], b[1, 0]}, {b[0, 1], b[1, 1]}};
```

--- end edit ---

Answer (score 8):

Here's a fairly simple way of doing it (ignore the front end's syntax warning):

```
Function[, {##}, Listable][A, B]
(* {{{a[0, 0], b[0, 0]}, {a[1, 0], b[1, 0]}}, 
    {{a[0, 1],  b[0, 1]}, {a[1, 1], b[1, 1]}}} *)
```

Comment: Why does that work?  It is very interesting, but what if I want to make a[0,0] a list as well?

Comment: If you consider element-wise multiplication `A B`, that is possible because of the `Listable` attribute of `Times`. In other words, it threads over lists in its arguments. What I've done above is similar – it creates a pure function that "joins" the arguments (`{#}`) and threads it over lists (`Listable`). The omitted argument is taken as `Null`. I don't understand what you mean by wanting to make `a[0,0]` a list as well, as it's no longer element-wise join, as you wanted.

Comment: +1. You are too fast, I am running out of tricks :-)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a pedagogical alternative

```
(A + B) /. Plus -> List
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in general. Think about what happens if the elements of A and B are numbers.

Comment: sure. as mentioned: it is just pedagogical in that sense that it is easy to understand and you don't have to use Function with a Null argument.

Answer (score 6):

In the spirit of Rolf Mertig's answer we can abuse a system function with the attribute `Listable` to effect our join.  By simultaneously using an invalid syntax we can avoid undesired evaluation.  I chose `Re`:

```
threadJoin = Quiet[Re @ ##] /. Re -> List &;
```

Now:

```
threadJoin[
 {1, 2, 3},
 {4, 5, 6}
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}
> ```

```
threadJoin[
 {{a[0, 0], a[1, 0]}, {a[0, 1], a[1, 1]}},
 {{b[0, 0], b[1, 0]}, {b[0, 1], b[1, 1]}},
 {{c[0, 0], c[1, 0]}, {c[0, 1], c[1, 1]}}
]
```

> ```
> {{{a[0, 0], b[0, 0], c[0, 0]}, {a[1, 0], b[1, 0], c[1, 0]}},
>    {{a[0, 1], b[0, 1], c[0, 1]}, {a[1, 1], b[1, 1], c[1, 1]}}}
> ```

```
threadJoin[
 {{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}, {11, 22, 33}},
 {{{a4, a5, a6}, {b4, b5, b6}, {c4, c5, c6}}, {44, 55, 66}}
]
```

> ```
> {{{{a1, a4}, {a2, a5}, {a3, a6}}, {{b1, b4}, {b2, b5}, {b3, b6}}, {{c1, c4},
>     {c2, c5}, {c3, c6}}}, {{11, 44}, {22, 55}, {33, 66}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

From your comment "what if I want to make a[0,0] a list as well?" I think Daniel's `Transpose` method is the way to go but the second parameter was never generalized.  I believe you could use:

```
elementJoin[a_, b_] := 
  Transpose[{a, b}, RotateRight @ Range @ ArrayDepth @ {a, b}]

elementJoin[
 {1, 2, 3},
 {4, 5, 6}
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}
> ```

```
elementJoin[
 {{1, 2, 3}, {11, 22, 33}},
 {{4, 5, 6}, {44, 55, 66}}
]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{11, 44}, {22, 55}, {33, 66}}}
> ```

```
elementJoin[
 {{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}, {11, 22, 33}},
 {{{a4, a5, a6}, {b4, b5, b6}, {c4, c5, c6}}, {44, 55, 66}}
]
```

> ```
> {{{{a1, a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6}}, {{b1, b2, b3}, {b4, b5, b6}},
>     {{c1, c2, c3}, {c4, c5, c6}}}, {{11, 44}, {22, 55}, {33, 66}}}
> ```

Note that this last output is not the same as that produced by R.M's `Listable` function:

```
Function[, {##}, Listable][
 {{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}, {11, 22, 33}},
 {{{a4, a5, a6}, {b4, b5, b6}, {c4, c5, c6}}, {44, 55, 66}}
]
```

> ```
> {{{{a1, a4}, {a2, a5}, {a3, a6}}, {{b1, b4}, {b2, b5}, {b3, b6}}, {{c1, c4},
>  {c2, c5}, {c3, c6}}}, {{11, 44}, {22, 55}, {33, 66}}}
> ```

Choose according to your needs.