# How to combine elements of two matrices?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Given two matrices m1 and m2, e.g.:

```
m1 = {{a1, b1}, {c1, d1}}
m2 = {{a2, b2}, {c2, d2}}
```

How can one obtain the following?

```
{{f[a1, a2], f[b1, b2]}, {f[c1, c2], f[d1 ,d2]}}
```

I found this solution

```
MapThread[f, {m1, m2}, 2]
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: is defining `f` as `Listable`
 an option?

Comment: Yes. It is an option.

Comment: This is an exact copy of a question I asked here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29856/correct-way-to-map-a-function-on-entries-down-the-pages-in-a-3d-matrix where the example I had there had 3 matrices, and you have 2 matrices. So you can use the same exact answers there (there are total of 8 ways shown all together there)

Comment: @Nasser you're correct. Although I think Pinguin's `Listable` method is simpler than the solutions proposed on your question.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for pointing me to your question!

Comment: @rcollyer, yes, I said so in the comment below. The question is the same though, but the answer given here is much simpler.

Comment: @Nasser never noticed the comment. :P

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17400

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the comments, `Listable` is a possible way for you. Thus, you could:

```
SetAttributes[f,Listable]
```

and then simply:

```
f[m1,m2]
```

to obtain:

> {{f[a1, a2], f[b1, b2]}, {f[c1, c2], f[d1, d2]}}

**EDIT**

To apply this on a built-in (non-`Listable` function) like `List` on could do, as noted by @rcollyer below:

```
f[m1,m2]/.f->List
```

(please also note his comment with regard to `Block`!)

**Pure function approach**

I also propose the following idea, which saves us from the trouble of making the keyfunction `Listable`:

```
Function[{x, y}, anyFunction[x, y], Listable][m1, m2]
```

The idea is to use a pure function that is `Listable`, thus we do not have to modify `anyFunction`. This works with `List` (instead of `anyFunction`) etc. as well.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: What if f is just List? Is there a special solution for that case?

Comment: @dnet `f[m1, m2] /. f -> List`. I would wrap the whole thing in `Block`, though: e.g. `Block[{f}, SetAttributes[f,Listable]; f[m1, m2] /. f -> List]`, as this eliminates unintentional interactions with the rest of your code.

Comment: You should add this nice answer to my question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29856/correct-way-to-map-a-function-on-entries-down-the-pages-in-a-3d-matrix also. No one thought about it this way. Would have accepted this one if I saw it there :)

Comment: @Pinguin I would have given you +1, but I forgot. The update, though seals it. :)

Comment: rcollyer: Thanks! @Nasser: Ok, I'll add it there and let the moderators decide what to close as duplicate (or leave it all open) (will add a link to this question there as well)

Comment: @PinguinDirk don't add it. A close and merge can be done.

Comment: I think it is good to keep this question separate. My question presented each 2D matrix as being already a page of one 3D matrix variable. This question started by giving each 2D matrix as a separate variable. I think it is this slight way of looking at it, made it hard to notice that one can use Listable. But your answer will work for me, if one uses each page as separate matrix and also assume `f` is Listable (I also did not assume this in my question, which is also a reason may be no one thought of your answer as possible way of doing it).

Comment: uhmmm. Now I am definitely confused :). I guess I won't do anything till a mod decides how to proceed... Don't wanna double-post the same idea. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Nasser, for your question it would just be case of applying the listable function `f@@m`

Comment: @Nasser, I think it's fairer if I leave it for Pinguin

Comment: @SimonWoods: Thanks for the comment, and it seems mod's don't merge/close/whatever the questions, so I just added this idea to Nasser's question. It's getting harder these days to be aware of all the related questions...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not in spirit and purely for this configuration (i.e. not general enough)

`f@@@ # & /@ {m1, m2}`