# Element-wise join multiple lists

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

The following question is related to: [Elementwise join](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/elementwise-join/17404#17404)

I have the following code:

```
listStrings = {"LCM[48,108]", "LCM[450,780]", "LCM[49,66,33]", 
  "LCM[10,15,18 ]", "LCM[8,16,25]", "LCM[32,45,50]", "LCM[125,325]", 
  "LCM[258,645]"};

listData = {LCM[48, 108], LCM[450, 780], LCM[49, 66, 33], 
   LCM[10, 15, 18], LCM[8, 16, 25], LCM[32, 45, 50], LCM[125, 325], 
   LCM[258, 645]};

primeFactors = FactorInteger[listData];
```

As output I would like to have such a table:

[image]

From [Elementwise join](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/elementwise-join/17404#17404) I could reproduce with:

```
Grid[MapThread[Riffle[{#1}, {#2}] &, {listData, primeFactors}], 
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

the last two columuns:

[image]

How can I join to this the first column (`listStrings`) at left as shown in the table above?

Is it possible to generalize the code for any number of columns (lists)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Grid[Transpose[{listStrings, listData, primeFactors}], 
  Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image: grid]

seems to work.

Comment: so simple ... I am using Transpose always to plot 2d data with ListPlot ... here I was blind ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
 {"LCM[48,108]", "LCM[450,780]", "LCM[49,66,33]", 
  "LCM[10,15,18]", "LCM[8,16,25]", "LCM[32,45,50]", "LCM[125,325]", 
  "LCM[258,645]"};

Grid[
 Join[
  {{"LCM", "Result", "FactorInteger"}},
  Transpose[{list, #, FactorInteger@#}] &[ToExpression@list]
  ],
 Alignment -> {{Left, Right, Left}},
 Background -> {None, {LightGray}},
 Dividers -> All,
 Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks al lot ... great and powerfull ...