# Add new coordinate to list of lists with different lengths

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to turn the list

```
list1 = {{a},{b,c},{d,e,f,g}}
```

into

```
{ {{1,a}}, {{2,b},{2,c}}, {{3,d}, {3,e}, {3,f}, {3,g}} }
```

How can I do this? I've tried different forms of `Map` but none is working.

Comment: Maybe `MapThread[Thread[{#2, #1}] &, {list1, Range[Length[list1]]}]` or `Thread[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ Transpose[{Range[Length[list1]], list1}` ?

Comment: Perhaps Table[{ConstantArray[i, Length[list1[[i]]]], 
   list1[[i]]}\[Transpose], {i, 1, Length@list1}]

Comment: Thanks, it's working!

Comment: @b.gatessucks There is a bracket missing right at the end of your second solution.

Comment: Sorry - cut and paste didn't quite work for me in StackExchange - 
 try this - Table[Transpose[{ConstantArray[i, Length[list1[[i]]]], 
   list1[[i]]}], {i, 1, Length@list1}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solutions by @b.gatessucks

```
MapThread[Thread[{#2, #1}] &, {list1, Range[Length[list1]]}]
(*or*)

Thread[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ Transpose[{Range[Length[list1]], list1}]
```

I could not get @user11946's to work.

> My own contribution is a generalisation.

The coordinates follow a geometric sequence: the first element is 1, the next two are 2, the next four are 4 etc. This can be tabulated as

```
list1 = {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e, f, g}}

bill = Table[
ConstantArray[i, 
FoldList[Times, 1, Table[2, Length[list1]]][[i]]], {i, 1, 
Length[list1]}]
```

[In this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/elementwise-join) I found many useful ways for element-wise `Join` in matrixes. I use one of them and define

```
threadJoin = Quiet[Re@##] /. Re -> List &;

threadJoin[bill, list1]
```

with the desired output. Most importantly, this is now marked as answered.

Answer (score 4):

```
MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, list1]
```

> {{{1, a}}, {{2, b}, {2, c}}, {{3, d}, {3, e}, {3, f}, {3, g}}}